# Cap production deploy error: git permission deniedI have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, deployment, digital-ocean

I have been following https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04 
to deploy to the server but I get the following error.

```
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:walsh259/market2.git HEAD
      01 Permission denied (publickey).
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
```

has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Github Article](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) should point you in the right direction.  Check under deploy keys

Comment: I used this to generate the ssh key and add it to git hub and then ran "sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /deploy/market2/" Which gave permissions and is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the repository `walsh259/market2`, when authenticating with the public key with which you are authenticating.